# Settlers of Catan cities and knights mighty knights maximum numbers

Tags: catan, catan-cities-and-knights

Playing Settlers of Catan there have been a few instances where one runs out of Settlements or Cities (the pieces). How I have been playing it is that if you don't have it you can't build it.

However playing the expansion Cities and Knights for the first time I explored the Politics Calender which gives you the special of **"Fortress: You may promote strong knights to mighty knights"** Only then did I realize that there are only 2 Mighty Knight Token pieces. If the Politics special is to promote to Mighty Knights but only able to perform this for two knights(if they've not been promoted already) then it seems under powered compared to the other Building tree abilities.

My question is: Can you only play the 2 mighty knights during a game because there are only 2 mighty knight pieces?

Comment: IIRC, the limit on 5 settlements and 4 cities due to # of pieces is an actual game rule.

Comment: @HaoYe is it the same for knight pieces?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are always limited to the number of pieces you have, no matter what that piece is.

In the case of Cities and Knights, the Fortress does only allow you to upgrade your two strong knights (level 2) to mighty knights (level 3), which in itself is only an upgrade of 2 strength. However, in doing so, it also means that you can have up to six knights on the board - 2 of each level - compared to the 4 you can build without the Fortress. And in terms of total strength, you go from a maximum of 6 to a maximum of 12, so you're actually doubling your capacity to defend against the barbarian. And that's not even looking at the options of displacing strong knights on your roads.

Comment: I didn't realise this until I read your comment. I thought that anyone could upgrade all to Mighty Knights but that a Fortress gave you a quick promotion. Now that I understand that you CANNOT get Might Knights without Fortress I see that it is powerful.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, like the Settlements and Cities, you are constrained by the number of knights you have to promote to Mighty knights (or any other type) 2 of each.  You can always make house rules but the game was designed with the specific number of pieces they sent along.

Answer (score 0):

You should play with the number of pieces (cities or mighty knights) specified by the game rules. You in your example, you should play with only two mighty knights because that's what the rules specify.

Suppose you "lost" one of the two knight pieces and had only one. Then you could import an additional one from another set, or use a "token" for the "second" mighty knight piece called for by the game rules.